# Why this query doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why the query below doesn't work in SQL Server 2008?

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(INT, TEMP.observ_value) AS value
FROM
    (SELECT observ_value 
     FROM LAB_RESULTS
     WHERE observ_value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') TEMP  
WHERE 
    observ_value >= 190
```

Here, is the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SCREEN' to data type int.

The `observ_value` column is `varchar`. However, I have already only chosen the `int` values in the subquery.

Comment: just FYI, I tried the same query in MSSQL 2012, it works.

Comment: Show some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the SQL Server query optimiser can and will rearrange items from your query in ways that may cause errors to be introduced that weren't there in your original query. This is heavily dependent on the precise query plan that gets used, which in turn depends not only on the table definition and query text, but also on how your values are distributed.

In your case, it's possible that SQL Server will check `observ_value >= 190`, implicitly converting `observ_value` to `int`, before checking that `observ_value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`. Whether this is a valid re-ordering of your query is arguable, but even if it's not valid, it's something SQL Server does and something you have to work around.

Re-write your query to make sure no conversion of non-numeric values to `int` can ever be performed:

```
SELECT 
    TEMP.observ_value AS value
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
         WHEN observ_value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
         THEN CONVERT(INT, observ_value) END
         AS observ_value
     FROM LAB_RESULTS
     WHERE observ_value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') TEMP  
WHERE 
    observ_value >= 190
```

Comment: Sql server is not mysql, it will throw an error for WHERE 
    observ_value >= 190 if it`s not numeric

Comment: @Mihai I don't know if you mean "if observ_value's data type is not numeric" or "if observ_value's value is not numeric". If the former: SQL Server will happily convert `varchar` columns to `int` implicitly, and this is well documented and supported. If the latter, yes, hence the error the OP got, and I'm solving the error by making sure `observ_value` is *never* non-numeric: if the original value in the table contained any non-digit character, the `CASE` expression evaluates as `NULL`, which is safe to convert.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, observ_value) AS value
    FROM LAB_RESULTS
    WHERE  ISNUMERIC(observ_value)= 1
```

Comment: Are you saying this will get rid of the error? I don't see why it would, but I may be missing something. If you're not saying that, this should've been a comment.